# ios- Firebase event select_content does not show data based on parameters

Tags: xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

Upon logging into the console, selecting my app, then I select the iOS version and I'm presented with the dashboard. All of that looks good. Then I select the Events tab, and I see a list of all events that my app has logged. Again, this is all good. However, I want to be able to drill down and see reports based on the parameters that were passed with those events. in my iOS code I have the following:

```
NSString[] keys = { ParameterNamesConstants.ContentType, ParameterNamesConstants.ItemId };
NSObject[] values = { new NSString("content"),new NSString("id") };
var parameters = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(keys, values, keys.Length);
Analytics.LogEvent(EventNamesConstants.SelectContent, parameters);
```

I want to see parameters data from this event, but I cannot figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't drill down into each event parameter. The predefined event parameters will help with displaying data report.

Comment: The thing is, i can't see any parameter within select_content event although ContentType and ItemId are predefined parameters. I tried with audience too, but no result and i have 25 users who selected content after creating audience

Comment: That's what I meant. You can't see the parameters even with some predefined parameters/events. Those parameters are used for displaying the reports for now. Regarding audience, do you mean you don't see any audience results even though you have 25 users already or you already have 25 audience results but you can't see the parameters?

Comment: I can't see any audience results even though i have 25 users already and in audience section every audience except "All users" have <10. I have created ~15 users that correspond to audience's parameters after creating audience and all of them with different advertisement Id

Comment: Did you run 15 users on different devices or just on the same device? Also, you will need to have fresh install. There are multiple factors that result in a user for an audience definition. I tested a lot before and it is not as easy to just install an app and uninstall it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say fresh install? Every time i've uninstalled app, reset advertisement id on my iPhone device and installed it again. Unfortunately, i have only two devices.

Comment: I believe they have some kind of metrics to detect users that I don't know of but for sure installing and uninstalling the app on the same device won't help much. I tried like you did before and I couldn't make the audience users appear on the Audience tab as I thought.